# Laravel Homestead Vagrant WIndows. "No input file specified."

Tags: laravel, virtualbox, vagrant, homestead

Решил изучить Laravel, начал с установки и настройки. 
Установил Virtualbox, Vagrant. 
Делаю по уроку [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BB08hIBqQN0&list=PLD5U-C5KK50WGCou5NMvVNMglIhNhdLBV), 
Файл Homestead.yaml

```
folders:
- map: ~/code
  to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/homestead/public
```

После чего я перешел в каталог **/home/vagrant/code/homestead/** и выполнил
команду **composer create-project laravel/laravel .**, установилось успешно, в каталоге **/home/vagrant/code/homestead/** появился проект Laravel с следующим содержимым:

```
vagrant@homestead:/vagrant/code$ cd homestead
vagrant@homestead:/vagrant/code/homestead$ ls -l
total 198
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   4096 Nov 22 14:28 app
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   1686 Nov 22 14:28 artisan
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant      0 Nov 22 14:28 bootstrap
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   1550 Nov 22 14:28 composer.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 152126 Dec  2 17:01 composer.lock
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   4096 Nov 22 14:28 config
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   4096 Nov 22 14:28 database
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   1023 Nov 22 14:28 package.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   1138 Nov 22 14:28 phpunit.xml
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   4096 Nov 22 14:28 public
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   4094 Nov 22 14:28 readme.md
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant      0 Nov 22 14:28 resources
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant      0 Nov 22 14:28 routes
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant    563 Nov 22 14:28 server.php
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant      0 Nov 22 14:28 storage
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant      0 Nov 22 14:28 tests
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   8192 Dec  2 17:01 vendor
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant    537 Nov 22 14:28 webpack.mix.js
```

Файл HOSTS настроен, команды vagrant reload --provison и vagrant up --provision пробовал, не помогают.
При загрузке с браузера страницы http://homestead.test/ получаю: 
**No input file specified.**

Лог запуска vagrant

```
PS C:\Users\Stas\Documents\laravel-dev\homesteadnew> vagrant reload --provision
==> homestead-7: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> homestead-7: Vagrant has detected a configuration issue which exposes a
==> homestead-7: vulnerability with the installed version of VirtualBox. The
==> homestead-7: current guest is configured to use an E1000 NIC type for a
==> homestead-7: network adapter which is vulnerable in this version of VirtualBox.
==> homestead-7: Ensure the guest is trusted to use this configuration or update
==> homestead-7: the NIC type using one of the methods below:
==> homestead-7:
==> homestead-7:   https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/configuration.html#default-nic-type
==> homestead-7:   
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/networking.html#virtualbox-nic-type
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> homestead-7: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    homestead-7: Adapter 1: nat
    homestead-7: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> homestead-7: Forwarding ports...
    homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 4040 (guest) => 4040 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> homestead-7: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> homestead-7: Booting VM...
==> homestead-7: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    homestead-7: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    homestead-7: SSH username: vagrant
    homestead-7: SSH auth method: private key
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
==> homestead-7: Machine booted and ready!
==> homestead-7: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> homestead-7: Setting hostname...
==> homestead-7: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> homestead-7: Mounting shared folders...
    homestead-7: /vagrant => C:/Users/Stas/Documents/laravel-dev/homesteadnew
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: file...
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: inline script
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: inline script
    homestead-7: Unable to mount one of your folders. Please check your folders in Homestead.yaml
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: C:/Users/Stas/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20181202-8868-r4h3n4.sh
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Creating Certificate: homestead.test
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Creating Site: homestead.test
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: inline script
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Checking for old Schedule
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Clear Variables
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Restarting Cron
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Restarting Nginx
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Creating MySQL Database: homestead
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Creating Postgres Database: homestead
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Update Composer
    homestead-7: You are running composer as "root", while "/home/vagrant/.composer" is owned by "vagrant"
    homestead-7: You are already using composer version 1.7.3 (stable channel).
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: C:/Users/Stas/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20181202-8868-c917n7.sh
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: C:/Users/Stas/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20181202-8868-1pe8k2g.sh
PS C:\Users\Stas\Documents\laravel-dev\homesteadnew>
```

Так-же пытался вручную в папке homestead/public создать index.php с hello word - не работает. Получаю все тот-же **No input file specified.**

Гугл завален подобными вопросами от новичков, но ни одно решение мне не помогло.
С Уважением, Waik.

Answer (score -1):

Разобрался. Нужно было проваливаться в каталог /home/code/homestead **а не** /home/vagrant/code/homestead